# Image in GWT menubar instead of text

Tags: gwt, menubar

I am using MenuBar from GWT showcase. I want to add text in the menubar. Can you please let me know that in which way I can get it ?

Comment: where do you wanna add text? how you add menues is pretty well explained...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.  Maybe it will help somebody...

```
MenuBar HomeMenu = new MenuBar();
final String image = "<img src='"+GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "/images/down-arrow.png' height='25px' width='25px'/>";

SafeHtml addActivityImagePath = new SafeHtml() {
    @Override
    public String asString() {
        return image;
     }
 };

HomeMenu.addItem(new MenuItem(addActivityImagePath,mainMenu));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one also. Its given in MenuBar Docs API

```
public MenuItem addItem(java.lang.String text,
                        boolean asHTML,
                        MenuBar popup)
```

So, In your case,

```
final String image = "<img src='"+GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "/images/down-arrow.png' height='25px' width='25px'/>";


 HomeMenu.addItem(new MenuItem(image,true,mainMenu));
```

Comment: yeah that is also true. But there were same designing issues. So I have tried with POPUP and it worked well.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is not to hack anything. Just use the Image class:

```
MenuItem profileMenuItem = new MenuItem(new Image(TripImages.INSTANCE.getUserSmall()) + " Profile", true, profileMenuDropdown);
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `bundle` and `ImageResource`, you can use `AbstractImagePrototype`.

If `GlobalBundle.INSTANCE.home()` is my `ImageResource`, this makes it appear on the menu:

```
menu.addItem(AbstractImagePrototype.create(GlobalBundle.INSTANCE.home()).getSafeHtml(), ...);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here a [link](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~MenuBar) to a simple example of creating menubar. And [here](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~MenuItem) is an example of creating a menu with submenus.

Comment: Thanks but i want to add the icon for the menu instead of showing text. So this will not going to help me.

Comment: I would do it with CSS. You can select style for each item, in which the background will be required picture.

Answer (score -1):

```
    MenuBar HomeMenu = new MenuBar();
final String image = "<img src='"+GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "/images/down-arrow.png' height='25px' width='25px'/>";

SafeHtml addActivityImagePath = new SafeHtml() {
    @Override
    public String asString() {
        return image;
     }
 };

HomeMenu.addItem(new MenuItem(addActivityImagePath,mainMenu));
```