# How to add an icon to a MenuItem in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

How can I get add an icon with text to a menu item in GWT?
The following does not work:

```
<ui:with field='res' type='my.package.MyResources' />
<g:MenuItem text="test"><g:Image resource="{res.myIcon}" /></g:MenuItem>
```

Resulting error:

`Not allowed in an HTML context: <g:Image resource='{res.myIcon}'>`

```
public interface MyResources extends ClientBundle {
  @Source("myIcon.png")
  ImageResource myIcon();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9918937/687514

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MenuItem` allows only HTML or plain text as its content. So you cannot use an `Image` widget, but you can very well use an `<img>` element and retrieve the image URL from the `ImageResource` referenced by `<ui:with>` using `getSafeUri()` (you can call no-arg methods in `UiBinder` templates). In your case:

```
<g:MenuItem>
  <img src="{res.myIcon.getSafeUri}"/><span>Your text here</span>
</g:MenuItem>
```

Or programmatically, using a simple template:

```
public interface MyTemplate extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
  @Template("<img src=\"{0}\" /><span>{1}</span>")
  SafeHtml createItem(SafeUri uri, SafeHtml message);
}
```

instantiated via:

```
MyTemplate template = GWT.create(MyTemplate.class)
```

and used like so:

```
new MenuItem(template.createItem(
    yourResources.myIcon().getSafeUri(),
    SafeHtmlUtils.fromString("Your text here")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
  <g:MenuItem>
    <div class="className"/> MyMenuWithImg
  </g:MenuItem>
```

That css class have the `background image`.

Comment: No: `java.lang.String required, but {res.myIcon} returns com.google.gwt.resources.client.ImageResource: <div class='{res.myIcon}'`

Comment: What class name? The icon comes from `MyResources`, like edited above.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up extending the GWT `MenuItem` class in a way that one can supply an `ImageResource` from ui-binder:

```
class MyMenuItem extends MenuItem {
    @Uresstructor
    public resMenuItem(String text, ImageResource res) {
        super(SafeHtmlUtils.fromString(text));

        ImageResourceRenderer renderer = new ImageResourceRenderer();
        setHTML(renderer.render(res) + "&nbsp;" + text);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<ui:with field='res' type='path.to.MyIconResources' />

<g:MenuBar>
 <my:MyMenuItem text="test" icon="{res.myIcon}" />
</g:MenuBar>
```

If anyone comes up with a better idea (now or in the future) please comment accordingly.